# SQL Functions That Call On Other Functions

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I have created a function named fnDiscountPrice that takes one parameter (ItemID) and calculates the discounted price for that Item:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnDiscountPrice (@ItemID INT)
RETURNS MONEY
AS
    BEGIN
        RETURN (SELECT (ItemPrice - DiscountAmount)
        FROM OrderItems
        WHERE ItemID = @ItemID
        )
    END;
```

Now I am trying to created another function named fnItemTotal that takes one parameter (ItemID) and calculates the Total Item Price (which is DiscountPrice * Quantity) so I want to use my previous function inside of this one.

This is what I have come up with:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnItemTotal (@ItemID INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
    BEGIN
        RETURN (SELECT (dbo.fnDiscountPrice(@ItemID) * Quantity) AS 'TotalAmount'
        FROM OrderItems
        )
    END;
```

It successfully created this function in my database. However I cannot call it. When I try to call my function using:

```
SELECT dbo.fnItemTotal(3);
```

It returns this MSG:

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

And if I hold my mouse over the highlighted errors in my code it gives me the tooltip:

```
Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.fnItemTotal", or the name is ambiguous.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: `Subquery returned more than 1 value`. You can't use the result of a subquery as a single field if the subquery returns more than one value. Either adjust your function so that it only returns one value, or adjust your query.

Comment: I fixed it myself. I was missing a `WHERE ItemID = @ItemID` clause in my function fnItemTotal. After adding this it works.